# Куда деплоить java проект?

Tags: java, free, deploy

Куда можно задеплоить java проект, к сожалению база данных Cassandra, в связи с этим на Heroku платно. Есть ли бесплатные deploy системы для такой БД?

Comment: А если серьезно то попробуйте задеплоить в Docker и полезно и нужно.

Comment: Туда можно заполненную БД перенести?

Comment: и других вариантов нету?

Comment: Вариантов много, но тренд такой что у всех всои настройки приложения и само разворачивание не простое занятие. Docker image это современный экзешник готовый к работе везде где есть hub

Comment: Имея файл готовый для поедания докером можно не сильно беспокоится о деплойменте

Comment: А можно ли как-то сделать подмену БД непосредственно на deploy? Или это придется все сущности заново описывать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, как уже сказали, поставить Docker.

Cassandra скорее всего захочет много оперативки, и найти бесплатный сервер может не получиться.

Если это не продакшн, а демо, то можно развернуть у себя локально в Docker.

При этом нужен:

- или внешний IP дома
- или *хитрый* прокси (https://github.com/fatedier/frp) на самом простом VPS

- бесплатный динамический DNS

Самый простой VPS -- где-то <2 у. е. / мес;
У амазона были бесплатные на время, но так кредитка всё равно нужна.